# Is there a web interface for my BT ADSL modem (upstream of my router) - if so, how do I reach it?

Tags: networking, router, modem, bt-infinity

My ASUS router's IP address is 192.168.1.1, I can view that fine and log in to look at logs and change settings etc etc.

We have one of the small white BT modem boxes between the phone line coming into the house and the ASUS router.  Is there a way I can reach that, is there an interface that shows anything at all?  Or is it out of reach?

Comment: What do you mean by "small white modem box"? Do you mean an [Openreach Fibre Modem](https://www.bt.com/help/broadband/buttons-and-sockets-on-the-openreach-fibre-modem) or just a [BT Master Socket](https://www.bt.com/help/broadband/getting-set-up/home-networks/a-wired-home-network/what-type-of-master-socket-have-i-got-) of some description? Chances are that the fibre modem is only accessible from the Openreach Fibre side (so that they can perform updates) but as far as you are concerned it is simply a "dumb" fibre to ethernet bridge.

Comment: I do indeed mean the Openreach Fibre Modem, thank you.  I feel I've been inside its web interface before many years ago, but maybe I've imagined it!

Comment: It depends on the Fibre modem (and I have no idea about the Openreach one), but assuming it connects via ethernet to your router, try connecting a computer directly to it. See if you get a DHCP response, look at the assigned address, then try to guess where a web interface could be. None of this will work by default as long as you are going through the ASUS.